# Change key binding for autocomplete in haskell-vim-now

Tags: linux, haskell, vim, autocomplete

I have installed the Vim plugin [haskell-vim-now](https://github.com/begriffs/haskell-vim-now/) in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and in Xubuntu 14.04 LTS.

After using the plugin in Ubuntu, I could use the autocompletion with `Ctrl-space`. However, when I installed it in Xubuntu, the `Ctrl-space` key would not work. The only way I made the autocompletion work was with the key `Ctrl-@`.

I looked in the .vimrc file generated by haskell-vim-now, and the problem seems to be in the following line:

```
inoremap <Nul> <c-r>=SuperTabAlternateCompletion("\<lt>c-x>\<lt>c-o>")<cr>
```

It seems to me that `<Nul>` binds to `Ctrl-space` in Ubuntu and to `Ctrl-@` in Xubuntu.

How can I change the configuration so that `<Nul>` binds to `Ctrl-space` in Xubuntu (so that autocompletion may be done with `Ctrl-space`).

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just edit that line in your `~/.vimrc` to:

```
inoremap <c-space> <c-r>=SuperTabAlternateCompletion("\<lt>c-x>\<lt>c-o>")<cr>
```

Mappings take the following basic form: `{mode}map {key} {lhs}`. For more information on mappings see `:h :map` as well as `:h key-notation`.

Haskell-vim-now is not a plugin it is a more like vim config distribution. Now from what I see Haskell-vim-now seems to try and play as nice as possible for a vim distribution, but it still installs many vim plugins and makes many customizations. Such numerously and rapid changes to a newer vimmer's config often causes confusion because they are both using someone else's customization and they did not learn all the intermediary Vim steps. So I caution you against such distribution and to slowly build up your own `vimrc` as you learn.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. For the edit, are you sure it is correct? I tested `inoremap =SuperTabAlternateCompletion("\c-x>\c-o>")` and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Konstantinos, my mistake I didn't format my post correctly. I have updated the post

Comment: Also, I'd advise you make your customizations to `~/.config/haskell-vim-now/vimrc.local` since `.vimrc` is symlinked to a file in version control. Using the .local file allows you to update haskell-vim-now more easily later on if you need to. See the [readme](https://github.com/begriffs/haskell-vim-now#customizing).

Answer (score 0):

The reason `<c-space>` in `inoremap <c-space> <c-r>=SuperTabAlternateCompletion("\<lt>c-x>\<lt>c-o>")<cr>` did not work for me was because there was a conflit with an existing `<c-space>` key shortcut.

Once I solved the conflict, the Vim autocompletion shortcut worked.